# Resizing Squarespace header image container doesn't resize image inside

Tags: css, image, video, css-selectors, squarespace

I've noticed when I try to resize the container of a header image or video on Squarespace, it doesn't resize the video or image inside of it. For example, on https://forgwinnett.org it looks like the video is only taking up half of the landing screen but it's actually not - the video is still rending at 100% view width and height but I'm covering up half of it.

This kind of stinks and isn't specific to this particular template. I would love to know how to make the video/image responsive.

```css
div[data-url-id="pledge"] div.title-desc-wrapper.over-image.has-main-image.has-background-video {
    height: 55vh;
}
```

This resizes the video container, but the video or image doesn't resize with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<iframe>` element inherits the following:

```css
.sqs-video-background .background-video {
  min-height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

This means that no matter what `height` value you specify, the minimum height of your `<iframe>` element must be at least 100% of the parent element... which itself is absolutely positioned and has a `height` of 100%, making it fill the entire page.

Based on your use of `height: 55vh !important` on your `.title-desc-wrapper` element, I can only assume that you're wanting your `<iframe>` element to have a 55vh height. To achieve that simply:

1. Reset the `min-height` from your `<iframe>` element to *initial*.
2. Add a `height` of 55vh to your `<iframe>` element.

Now depending on whether you want this to display behind your page `<header>` or not, you'll need to either offset your `<iframe>` element's height by the height of your `<header>` (using `calc(55vh + ...)`) or adjust the `top` property to push the `<iframe>` element down so that this no longer happens.

You'll end up with something which looks like this:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Your iframe is set to a specific width:

```
<iframe id="vimeoplayer" class="background-video ready" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/181653249?api=1&amp;background=1" style="width: 2640px; height: 990px; left: -729px; top: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Note the `style="width: 2640px; height: 990px; left: -729px; top: 0px;"`

I note that the value for `left` changes when the screen size changes in order to center the iframe under the content.

You need to either:

- Make the iframe the same width as the page (auto), or
- Make one of the parent divs between the iframe and the video the same width as the page, and centered.

Answer (score 1):

Use **"iframe#vimeoplayer"** as as selector to add your own css to affect video resizing.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to append this style:

```
.sqs-video-background {
    height: 61vh;
}
```

Comment: That resizes the container but not the image.